# Getting Windows Store app information programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Windows Phone Store [has an API](http://www.manyniches.com/windows-phone/crawling-the-windows-phone-marketplace/) for getting information about apps and reviews.

Does similar API exist for Windows Store apps?

Answer (score 2):

@sashaeve Windows Phone Store **does not** have an API to get information about apps and their reviews. The author of the post you linked to clearly says that this information was obtained by snooping on the wire (using Fiddler - you can use other tools as well) and seeing what format is the traffic flowing in when using Zune software (or the web marketplace) to browse the store.

You can basically do the same thing with Windows Store, and get the format of the calls made to the store when you see what's being sent on the wire while you browse the Store app on your Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Zune service has been replaced by http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com and has some limitations.